# "ld: unknown option: -Bsymbolic" when trying to build iniparser on OSX

Tags: macos, build, ld

I'm trying to build http://github.com/ndevilla/iniparser on OSX, but getting:

```
~/ make
compiling src/iniparser.c ...
compiling src/dictionary.c ...
a - src/iniparser.o
a - src/dictionary.o
ld: unknown option: -Bsymbolic
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libiniparser.so] Error 1
```

This seems to not be a known issue with the code itself. What do I need to adjust on my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-Bsymbolic` flag specified in the `Makefile` of that project is specific to the GNU linker and platforms using the ELF binary format. OS X uses neither. The `Makefile` has several other flags that aren't compatible with the OS X toolchain, such as the use of the `.so` extension for shared libraries rather than `.dylib`, and another unsupported linker flag (`-Wl,-soname=…`). You should be able to remove the unsupported linker flags and then fix up the file extensions to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

Using bdash's answer you can build iOS openssl-1.1.1 by doing the following:

```
sed -ie "s!-Bsymbolic! !" "Makefile"
sed -ie "s/-Wl,-soname=libssl\$(SHLIB_EXT)/ /g" "Makefile"
sed -ie "s/-Wl,-soname=libcrypto\$(SHLIB_EXT)/ /g" "Makefile"
sed -ie "s/--version-script=libcrypto.map/ /g" "Makefile"
sed -ie "s/--version-script=libssl.map/ /g" "Makefile"
```