# Cannot compile pip package in macOS "Big Sur" and python 3.8: "ld: unknown option: -Bsymbolic"

Tags: python, linker-errors, macos-big-sur

I try to install [Dedalus software](https://dedalus-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) on macOS Big Sur inside the Python 3.8 conda environment.

I have installed the environment using [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DedalusProject/dedalus/master/docs/install.sh) recommended by the Dedalus authors.

During installation, the pip-initiated compilation fails

```
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib -L/Users/dim
a/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib -L/Users/dima/sw/conda/envs
/rwth09/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib -L/Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -
mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -isystem /Users/dima/sw/co
nda/envs/rwth09/include -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/dedalus/libraries/fftw/fftw_wrappers.o -L/Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib -L/Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib -L/Us
ers/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib -L/Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib -lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/dedalus/libraries/fftw/fftw_wrappers.cpython-38-darwin.so -X
linker -Bsymbolic -Wl,--whole-archive /Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib/libfftw3.a /Users/dima/sw/conda/envs/rwth09/lib/libfftw3_mpi.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive                                 
  ld: unknown option: -Bsymbolic                                                                                                                                                                 
  clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)                                                                                                             
  error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

**UPDATED on 15 Jan 2021.** The solution to the problem was installation of clang 11 instead of clang 10 that was installed by `conda` automatically.

Comment: Possibly related: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/compiling-error-after-upgrading-to-macos-big-sur/19309

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15106019/8593689):

> The `-Bsymbolic` flag ... is specific to the GNU linker and platforms using the ELF binary format. OS X uses neither.

I believe you should report the use of the `-Bsymoblic` flag to build Dedalus software as a Mac bug.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it feels like the installation script uses a compiler (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang) that does not work for the new macOS.

Comment: I think `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang` should be the correct compiler. I think the problem is they are using a flag that is not supported by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a Mac myself, but why don't you try to download python 3.9.1 on https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/. I don't really know if this will run on Big Sur but, you might try it.

Comment: I  prefer to use conda-provided Python.